# Static linking with pthreads & stdc++?

Tags: linux, linker, pthreads, libstdc++

Is it possible to statically link my program with libpthreads and libstdc++ on Linux?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, with `-static` as per normal.

Comment: I want to create an .so statically linked with the libraries above. -static causes .a to be produced.

Comment: Then why didn't you ask for that originally?